# Looping through specific directories in linux

Tags: unix

I have a directory structure something like this:20160101 20160102 and so on. here 20160101 represents year month and day respectively.I have such directories for the entire month.(20160101....20160131). Among these I need to iterate from 20160101 to 20160123. Can someone help me with this using for loop

Thanks in advance

Comment: pai Loop within your directory with ls -option and within your loop use while ( some condition)  like checking you have reached to the required directory name till then keep on appending file name in array.And when you get the final directory name just exit from the loop.

Comment: You have a directory in which you have multiple directory right?

Comment: You are welcome..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate on what you want to do?

Here is a loop which will go through all the directories you specified and print out their names. (And it will stop after getting the directory `20160123`)

```
for dir in *201601*; do
    echo $dir
    if [ "$dir" == "20160124" ]; then
        exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: But Farhan this will list till 31 jan..I want only till 23 jan

Comment: Okay, I added that in there, now it will stop after 23 Jan :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution:-)